# Sorting of two different records referencing their dates

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I just want to ask if comparing of each fields on separate object is possible in order to show first the most recent.

Example, I have `Object A` and `Object B`, and Object A has `Hired_Date__c` , and `Object B` has `Hired_Date__c` also,

is it possible to sort them in a way of comparing using comparable.

```
if(Object A.Hired_Date__c > Object B.Hired_Date__c){
   return 1;
}

else if (Object A.Hired_Date__c < Object B.Hired_Date__c){
   return -1;
}

else {
    return 0;
}
```

so that I could display on visualforce page the arrangement of 
Object A1
Object B2,
so on . . 
or how could I achieve to sort this 2 different records?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to write a [Comparable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm) wrapper class that can work with various SObject types and fields:

```
public class DateFieldComparable implements Comparable {

    private SObject sob;
    private SObjectField field;

    public DateFieldComparable(SObject sob, SObjectField field) {
        this.sob = sob;
        this.field = field;
    }

    public Integer compareTo(Object o) {

        DateFieldComparable that = (DateFieldComparable) o;

        Date thisValue = (Date) this.sob.get(field);
        Date thatValue = (Date) that.sob.get(that.field);

        if (thisValue < thatValue) return -1;
        else if (thisValue > thatValue) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }

    public SObject getSObject() {
        return sob;
    }
}
```

that can then be used like this:

```
// Wrap and sort
DateFieldComparable[] fcs = new DateFieldComparable[] {};
for (Project__c p : projects) {
    fcs.add(new DateFieldComparable(p, Project__c.MyDateField__c));
}
for (assignment__c : assignments) {
    fcs.add(new DateFieldComparable(a, Assignment__c.OtherDateField__c));
}
fcs.sort();

// Pull back out the sorted objects
SObject[] sobs = new SObject[] {};
for (FieldComparable fc : fcs) {
    sobs.add(fc.getSObject());
}
```

This code is using the [SObjectField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectField.htm) token to represent a field which has the benefit that the compiler checks that the field exists. But if it is more convenient, you can use a string that holds the field API name because there is an [SObject.get](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) available for both types.

**PS**

Changed to a specific data type per sfdcfox's comment.

Comment: +1 This code won't compile, though, because you can't actually use inequality operators on Object, so they'd have to be prepared to use a concrete data type (e.g. Date), or build some sort of plug-in interface.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks, had a bad feeling about that but didn't try it... Changed code to `Date` type.

Comment: Hi @KeithC thank you very much! for confirmation only, did you changed it already the date u've trying to say from the above code?

Comment: Hi @KeithC I'm currently suffering this error. ''Project__c.Start_Date__c does not belong to SObject type Assignment__c" 

when I'm trying to make a for loop on assignment and project.

Comment: @RonaldPascual A field token for the `Assignment__c ` object would be `Assignment__c.xxx__c`: if the date field there has the API name `Start_Date__c` then it would be `Assignment__c.Start_Date__c`.

Comment: @KeithC yes, I know it actually. I follow your instruction on Wrap and Sort. But that's the error returning to me.

Comment: @RonaldPascual My fault. I've now changed in the code above `Date thatValue = (Date) that.sob.get(field);` to `Date thatValue = (Date) that.sob.get(that.field);` which should fix it. (The code was using the same `field` for both objects instead of using the appropriate `field` for each object.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that should be no problem: This is exactly what the Comparable interface is for.

```
global class Object implements Comparable { // Change this "Object" to your object name
    Date hiredDate;

    public Object(Date hd){ // Change this "Object" to your object name
        hiredDate = hd;
    }

    global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) { // DO NOT change this "Object" to your object name
        Object compareToObject = (Object) compareTo;
        // Change this "Object" to your object name 
        // This line is important, make sure you cast to your custom object

        if(hiredDate == compareToObject.Hired_Date__c) return 0;
        if(hiredDate > compareToObject.Hired_Date__c) return 1;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Please refer to the documentation for more examples & explanations:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm

Comment: Hi @Koen Wesselman , I think my question is not cleared, so about that, but I'll give you more detailed, I have Professional_Skills__c, and inside the professional skills, I have 2 different record, project__c and assignment__c, and the project has date field, and assignment also has. so that inside on my professional skills list will be the mix project and assignment record.

example i have 3 assignment and 2 project. 
will result like this. 

1. assignment(March 2017)
2. project(February 2017)
3. assignment1(January 2017)
4. project(December 2016)
5. assignment3(November 2016)